# Nullinjectorerror: no provider for httpclient! without app.module.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient, ionic6

I'm trying to read a JSON in Ionic Angular with HttpClient, but I get this error "nullinjectorerror: no provider for httpclient!".

The issue is that the lastest version of angular doesn't generate app.module.ts.

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ficha-evento',
  templateUrl: './ficha-evento.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ficha-evento.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class FichaEventoPage implements OnInit {

  event:any=[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvnt().subscribe(res=>{
      /*console.log("res",res);*/
      this.event=res;
    });
  }
  
  getEvnt(){
    return this.http
    .get('assets/eventos.json')
    .pipe(
      map((res:any)=>{
        return res.data;
      })
    )
  }

}
```

Any idea? thanks!!

I'm trying to import HttpClientModule in the page.module.ts, but it doesn't work. I also tried to generate appModule manually... doesn't work either.

Now I'm looking for other ways to acces Json files...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To provide `HttpClient` in standalone app we could do

**main.ts**

```
import {provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
```

Comment: Where can we find more about this. I see things like provideHttpClient, provideAnimations. How can I find out these new providers

Comment: Have you checked angular new doc:https://angular.dev/?

Answer (score 17):

In Angular 17 where `standalone` option is set by default, `app.config.ts` file is generated in `src/app/` and `provideHttpClient()` can be added in the list of `providers` in `app.config.ts`:

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ],
};
```

Comment: This has worked. To add context that the 'app.config.ts' is pulled from main.ts i.e.: 



```import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

You should only have the httpClientModule in the root of your project

Then you should use a service class to call the api that can be achieved like this

I wanna note this is if you use the classic module style applications

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ficha-evento',
  templateUrl: './ficha-evento.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ficha-evento.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class FichaEventoPage {
  events$ = this.eventService.getEvents();

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}
}
```

component.html

```
<div>{{ events$ | async }}</div>

<!-- for seeing object content (For debugging) -->
<pre>{{ events$ | async | json }}</pre>
```

event.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
  getEvents() {
    return this.http
    .get('/assets/eventos.json')
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map((res:any)=>{
        return res.data;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I keep getting the same exception. I also tried to add eventService in pageModule as a provider. Doesn't work neither.

Comment: Note i have seen projects where people have another httpModule which auto completes from the packages i cant remember the name of the project

Any how to really help you i need more project wide info